# 2D Primitive Arrays in Objective C on the heap

Tags: objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want a primitive 2D float array on the heap. I could use NSMutableArray as a wrapper, but for performance, I want to work with just primitives.

A way to do it in Objective-C WITH objects:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:DIM1];

for (int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++) {
    array[i] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:DIM2];
}
```

This is what I would do in C:

```
float **array = new float*[DIM1];
for(int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
    hotplate[i] = new float[DIM2];
}
```

How would I accomplish this is Objective-C?

Comment: You can use the C approach in Objective-C, because Objective-C is a superset of C.  Do you have a reason not to?

Comment: Just use the C version and work with floats. You can always use boxing syntax `@(...float...)` to easily make an `NSNumber *` from a primitive float.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is just a set of extensions on top of C. The C parts (like arrays of floats) are unchanged. Your problem is that what you're calling "C" here is actually C++. This is how you do it in C:

```
float **array = malloc(DIM1 * sizeof(float*));
for(int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++) {
    hotplate[i] = malloc(DIM2 * sizeof(float));
}
```

(Of course, the actual float arrays contain heap garbage at this point, so you might want to initialize those too.)

Comment: I don't think that `for` loop is 100% absolutely necessary.

Comment: @H2CO3: Best I can figure, it may or may not be absolutely necessary depending on the context. I was just offering the C equivalent of the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

> This is what I would do in C: `float **array = new float*[DIM1];`

Nah, that's C++. This is what I would do in C:

```
float (*arr)[DIM1] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * DIM2);
```

And suddenly you got rid of all the ugly for loop, yet you can have nice syntax for 2D subscripting.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your dimensions are constant (it seems).   You could do something like this.

```
typedef float two_dim_array [DIM1][DIM2];

extern int
main (void)
{

  two_dim_array *array = (two_dim_array *) malloc (sizeof(two_dim_array));
  (*array)[0][0] = 1.0;
  (*array)[2][2] = 4.0;
  printf ("%f, %f", (*array)[0][0], (*array)[2][2]);
}
```